# Conky interface

Tags: python, c, conky

I am investigating a way to access remotely statistics about a linux server, the kind of information that [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) would display.

Is there a way to interface with conky and obtain the statistics it displays? If not, can you recommend a good way to obtain this kind of statistics? (C/Cpp lib, or maybe python)?

Comment: You might find answers to your question on this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66921/can-conky-monitor-other-linux-computers-on-the-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have conky write to stdout (the `out_to_console` option) and redirect that to a file. Of course you'd still need to gain external access to the file.

Conky gets most of its data from the files in `sysfs` and `procfs`. You could write a program that gathers the information you need from there and puts it on a webpage that you can read remotely (assuming the server runs a webserver).

**Edit:** According to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface) the file format in `sysfs` files is really simple; there is only one floating point value (as text) per file.

Comment: Great! sysfs and procfs sound like what I needed. Can you recommend a good documentation for the file formats inside the folders?