# Is there a textual version of Conky?

Tags: conky

Is there a way to run conky *in* the terminal? I don't care about the graphics but I would like to have a window in screen that would effectively run as my 'conky' and display conky-like stats/scripts etc.

If this isn't possible, are there alternatives that do what I'm asking?

I found this [Conky interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691761/conky-interface) post which uses the `out_to_console` option. I don't really consider this a solution as I'm looking for something ncurses based.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [cli version of conky](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/conky-cli). On debian wheezy you can install it with:-

```
sudo apt-get install conky-cli
```

However, it will remove conky-std if you already have that installed.

Answer (score 1):

Further googling 'conky ncurses' led me full circle back to conky's documentation http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html.
There is an `out_to_ncurses` option.

Based on this post http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/howto-live-life-in-a-text-based-world-856017/#post4234633 you need to set `out_to_console` and `out_to_x` to `no` to get it to work.

I simply took my working graphical conky and set `out_to_console` and `out_to_x` to `no`  and `out_to_ncurses` to `yes` and commented out a line where I was setting the background image (not sure if this was necessary) and ran it and she worked like a charm!

HTH

N.B.: In the newer versions of conky, these argument take boolean values such as `true` or `false` instead of `yes` of `no`.